# E: Package 'gvfs-bin' has no installation candidate

Tags: docker, google-chrome, containers, apt, ubuntu-20.04

After installing Google Chrome in my Docker Container with

```
RUN wget -qO - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list \
    && sed -i '3 s/^/# /' /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install --allow-downgrades --no-install-recommends -y google-chrome-stable \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean
```

if I attempt to install more apt-packages,

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --allow-downgrades --no-install-recommends -y gvfs-bin
```

I get an error of

```
E: Package 'gvfs-bin' has no installation candidate
```

or that

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any thoughts on how to debug this? I am on ubuntu 20.04 in a container.

Comment: Same situation here, any idea?